# How to override component template in joomla if user is logged in?

Tags: component, joomla-1.5

I am working on Joomla 1.5. I have to override Joomla default template of my component (Virtuemart). It's working fine. But problem is i have to override my template if user is logged in only. I have to check look like this :

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->guest==1){

// Not override my template 

}else{


// Override this template  

}
```

I know my condition works, but where should I write this condition. And if the condition is wrong then how can i do this?

Comment: Are you talking about some specific layout of the template or whole template?

Comment: Some specific ! :) Like com_virtuemart/views/user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would personally do is, use 2 sub templates.

So firstly, create your template override for the view that you want to use, and then create 2 new PHP files, so you directory structure will look like this:

```
tmpl/
   default.php
   default_guest.php
   default_loggedin.php
```

In your **default.php**, add the following:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if ($user->guest == 1)
{
    echo $this->loadTemplate('guest');
}
else
{
    echo $this->loadTemplate('loggedin');
}
```

Then in your **default_loggedin.php** add your code for the main template override.

In your **default_guest.php**, simply copy and paste the code from the default view.